# SQL Server 2008 backup from locked down hosting provider

Tags: sql-server-2008, dts, backup-strategies

I have a shared MS Sql 2008 database with my hosting provider and MS SQL Standard 2008 on my local box. They have the SQL Server locked down (rightly enough) but it menas I don't have sufficient privileges to use the backup database wizard or to generate scripts to create the database as a whole.

To get around this I have been running the a scheduled DTS job using the SQL Server Agent on the local box to pull the data off every night (sufficient enough) and I have an up to date script of all Stored Procedures logins etc in case something goes wrong at the host.

There are 2 problems I have with this.

Firstly if for some reason I'm not around when the hosting has a problem my next DTS job may, in the worst case scenario, overwrite all the local data with the nonsense or blank data.

Secondly it all seems a bit messy to have it this way and doesn't really allow me to swiftly get the DB back online if the worst should happen.

Any thoughts on what's the best way to run the backup with the current setup? Any opinions or suggestions welcome.

I'm thinking that long term my best option would be to have another SQL server at another hosting company and use my local SQL Server Agent to run an hourly DTS data copy from the master to the backup. That way I can setup a dns record for the master sql server which I can flick over quickly should one fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you talked to your host about this?  Most will allow you to send backup commands to SQL Server (or they will set it up for you) such that you can backup to a folder that you have external access to.  Typically this is to a protected folder on the FTP site on your web server (the same server where you upload your web content, but not in a folder that is publicly accessible).

If your host won't let you do something like this, switch hosts.

Comment: >>>switch hosts.

I'm starting think this might be a great option.